# How to Loop Through User Selected Range after Selection?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the For...Next Loop to change the PageField names in a PivotTable. Then, run some processing. When I explicitly state the Array items, I can get it to do what I want (The commented out attempt below).

I would rather just select a range (as the items already exist elsewhere in the workbook, on a different sheet), and run the macro.

I think there are some unnecessary lines in the For Loop, and that I'm not defining the Array correctly amongst other things. I've been stuck on this for too long. Thanks for any help. It's greatly appreciated.

I've included the whole `sub` just to be sure, despite it probably not being needed.

```
Sub CyclePages()

'Disables screen refreshing.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate 'SETTING SHEET TO WHERE THE USER DEFINED ARRAY IS.

Dim arrSht As Variant, i    
'arrSht = Array("Data1", "Data2") 'THIS WORKS.
arrSht = Array(Selection.Value) 'THIS DOES NOT WORK. IT ONLY RUNS THE FIRST ITEM.

For i = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)
    With Sheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name1").CurrentPage = _
        ("All")
        Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name1").CurrentPage = _
            (arrSht(i))
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        DoEvents

        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = arrSht(i)

        Report_Process 'Running extra processing.

    End With
Next i

'ReEnables screen refreshing.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Using selection.value on anything other than a single cell gives you a 2-d array (1 to # of rows, 1 to # of cols) so you cannot loop over it the same way you would with a 1-d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transfer the worksheet values to your variable, try...

```
arrSht = Selection.Value
```

Note that transferring worksheet values to your variable creates a two-dimensional array.  For example, let's say you select A1:A10, arrSht will be a 10-row by 1-column array.  So you'll need to access the items like this...

```
For i = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)
    Debug.Print arrSht(i, 1)
Next
```

However, let's say that you select A1:J1, arrSht will be a 1-Row by 10-column array.  And so you'll need to access the items like this...

```
For i = LBound(arrSht, 2) To UBound(arrSht, 2)
    Debug.Print arrSht(1, i)
Next
```

Comment: For what its worth (which might not be much), if the selection was a single column (e.g. A1:A10) you can use `arrSht = Application.Transpose(Selection.Value)` to create a one-dimensional array dimensioned `1 To 10`.  (And, if the source was on a single row, e.g. A1:J1, you can use `arrSht = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Selection.Value))` to create the one-dimensional array.)

Comment: Thanks to you both. The examples are very useful, and work. I appreciate it.